# dispatcher.dispatch() in action.js is giving me the error of dispatch is not a function

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor, flux

I am using flux version 3.1.3

I want to know why the dispatcher is not working. I'm getting the error:

> dispatch is not a function

```
_dispatcher_AppDispatcher__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.dispatch is not a function

AppActions.js file

import AppDispatcher from '../dispatcher/AppDispatcher';
import AppConstants from '../constants/AppConstants';

var AppActions = {

  searchMovies : function(movie){

 AppDispatcher.dispatch({type:AppConstants.SEARCH_MOVIES,payload:movie});
  }
}
export default AppActions;
```

AppStore.js  file

```
var ApDispatcher = require('../dispatcher/AppDispatcher');
var AppConstants = require('../constants/AppConstants');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var Assign = require('object-assign');
var AppAPI = require('../utils/AppAPI');
var AppActions = require('../actions/AppActions');
```

SearchForm.js file

```
class ApStore extends EventEmitter{

  action({type,payload}){

    switch (type) {

      case AppConstants.SEARCH_MOVIES:

        console.log(1);

        this.addTask(payload);

        break;

    }
  }

}

const store = new ApStore();

module.export = ApStore;

    import React from 'react';

import AppActions from '../actions/AppActions.js';


export default class SearchForm extends React.Component {

  onSubmit(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var movie = {

      title : this.refs.title.value.trim()

    }

    //console.log("searchform.js"+movie.title);

    AppActions.searchMovies(movie);

  }

  render() {

    return (

      <div className="search-form">

          <h1 className="text-center">search for a movie</h1>

          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>

              <div className="form-group">

                <input type="text" id="movieser" className="form-control" 
ref="title" placeholder="Enter movie name" />

              </div>

              <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block"> search 
movies</button>

          </form>

      </div>

    );

  }

}
```

Comment: can you show AppDispatcher file?

Comment: AppDispatcher. js file.                                               Import {Dispatcher} from 'flux' ;                               module. export = Dispatcher ;

Answer (score 0):

Your problem basically is that you need to construct your Dispatcher. As you say in your comment you are exporting Dispatcher. But you need to construct the dispatcher object.

Modify your AppDispatcher.js or your AppActions.js file.

For example add this to your AppAction.js file:

```
import AppDispatcher from '../dispatcher/AppDispatcher';
import AppConstants from '../constants/AppConstants';

const myDispatcher = new AppDispatcher();


var AppActions = {

  searchMovies : function(movie){

 myDispatcher.dispatch({type:AppConstants.SEARCH_MOVIES,payload:movie});
  }
}
export default AppActions;
```

This is only an example, just to show where is your problem.